# Defining Midnight Commander's External Editor on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, text-editors, midnight-commander

I'm new to Midnight Commander. Very impressed so far. I'm working in both Mac OS and Windows, and would like to use vim as my external editor. That seems to be the default external editor on the Mac, so no problem there. In Windows, I defined the environment variable

`set EDITOR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe`

The problem is that when I edit a file, mc is inserting a `/C` between %EDITOR% and the filename, like so:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe" /C C:/Users/path/file`

Vim thinks that `/C` is a file, and creates a buffer for it. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: To clarify, I want to prevent the `/C` being added to the command line. I understand that vim treats it as two files, and I don't want that to change.

Comment: This is a really kludgey solution, but you could add `-c "bd1"` to the end of the command, and the "file" `/C` will be deleted as you start vim.

Comment: That worked, @DJMcMayhem, after I surrounded the vim full path in quotes. It does seem a bit kludgy. Do you (or anyone else) know why mc puts the `/C` in there?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about midnight-commander, just vim. Sorry about that!

Comment: Exactly the same problem, can not setup external editor on windows.

Comment: @SilverZachara An old question, I know, but apparently still a problem. One workaround would be to create an intermediate batch file, let's say, vim.bat, that starts vim: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`. `%0` contains the name of the batch file, `%1` will contain `/C`, so everything after that needs to be passed to vim.

Comment: This is a real good idea, I will try it , thx.

Comment: Ok, I have thought about it, and I can't have vim.bat like that in EDITOR env. variable, because it will affect the whole system, a solution would be to override EDITOR env. variable only for mc process ( I have solved this ), I have working solution, but still have problem with filepaths with witespaces, it is solvable, but I don't have time for this right now, when I solve it in future I past workaround here.